# EF6 - Mantaining base class record on delete

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance, orm

In my context I have two entities and the entity A inherits from B, they're mapped with the fluent API and works for some time.

But now I need to change it and when the base entity is deleted I need to maintain the entity **B** in the database.

Is it possible on EF6? The default behavior is to delete the records from both tables.

I thought of changing it from inheritance to composition but would prefer to just change the delete behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of inheritance did you applied? Table-per-Type? B has its own table and table A (which provides A additional properties) references table B, right? And when you delete A you want to keep the row in B, right?

Comment: I have two tables, one for the base class and one for the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could work as long as A is not Abstract.
If you delete a TPT mapped objects EF sends two delete Statements one for the base and one for the inherited table.

You could use a command interceptor to prevent the base delete from being executed or you could use stored procedure Mappings for deletion.

If A is abstract you could inherit a DeletedA class and create a corresponding entiry in the DeleteA Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thanks, it's really a way I haven't though before.